# ownership drupal directories

Tags: files

Would it be safe to say only the files directory should be owned by apache user ?

I have mine set files `apache:root`

And all other drupal directories `root:root` ?

My permissions are set to 755 for everything excepting 444 on settings.php

Actually my files I've set to 775 and have 
in www `chown -R root:apache html`

then `chown -R apache:root files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be safe with all folders being in 0775 and settings.php in 444.
However, if you would use FTP/SFTP to edit either the themes or any module files You may need to login with the "Owner" user, which may or may not be possible in a shared hosting environment.

So., depending on that you may choose. However, if you use SSh it will be not an issue.

Comment: actually have now apache:root on files and root:apache on all else. does this sound ok? access via ssh and only one user.

Comment: Yes, in that case, it is  fine. "root:apache" on everything is fine.